# JavaScript ajax function: different result / behaviour on several reloads

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

I've got a function that calls a web service method to get some bookmark counts of an user. Most of the time it works fine, but every 3-4th reload it shows the info sentence as if there were no bookmarks for the user, although there are some values returned by the web service. 
I have no idea why it randomly jumps in the if-statement for 0 result. If I reload the site again, it gets displayed correctly again. Some reloads later, wrong again. I am not able to fix this issue.

I'm using the following function:

```
function CallWcfAjax_GetBookmarkCount() {
    var recipeCount = 0;
    var productCount = 0;

    document.getElementById("bookmarkCountContent").innerHTML = '<h3>Merkliste</h3><div class="count"><span id="productCount"></span>Produkte</div><div class="count"><span id="recipeCount"></span>Rezepte</div>';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '_vti_bin/abc/UtilityService.svc/GetRecipeBookmarkCount',
        data: '{""}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            recipeCount = msg.d;
        },
        error: function (msg2) {
            alert("fehler:" + msg2.statusText);
            return;
        },
        complete: function (msg) {
            document.getElementById("recipeCount").innerHTML = recipeCount;
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '_vti_bin/abc/UtilityService.svc/GetProductBookmarkCount',
        data: '{""}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            productCount = msg.d;
        },
        error: function (msg2) {
            alert("fehler:" + msg2.statusText);
            return;
        },
        complete: function (msg) {
            document.getElementById("productCount").innerHTML = productCount;
            if (productCount < 1 && recipeCount < 1) {
                document.getElementById("bookmarkCountContent").innerHTML = '<h3>Merkliste</h3><p>Du hast keine Einträge auf deiner Merkliste. Du kannst einfach über den Button ein Rezept oder ein Produkt auf deine Merkliste hinzufügen.</p>';
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = CallWcfAjax_GetBookmarkCount;
```

What might be the probable issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: How did you verify that the browser receives what you think it does? FireBug? What is the HTTP status code for the requests? Should be in 2xx range for success.

Comment: I just noticed something... sometimes the first request (recipe) to the WebService is executed first and sometimes the second request (product) is executed first. If the latter happens, it won't work, because it is based on the fact that the first request must have been executed before that. Is there a way to tell it, that the first request must be executed first ALWAYS?

Comment: I think I just found a possible solution. I added two variables recipeExec and productExec. Each of them gets set to 1 if the request has been executed. Each request has now the if-statement to set the text for no results. But the if statement is only being entered when BOTH variables are set to 1. Now it doesn't matter which one is being executed first.